# how to use a file output in a loop Linux

Tags: java, linux, ksh

I have a file with a lot of jar names

jars.txt contains for example

```
axiom-api-1.2.13.jar
axiom-dom-1.2.13.jar
axiom-impl-1.2.13.jar
axis2-adb-1.6.2.jar
axis2-adb-codegen-1.6.2.jar
axis2-ant-plugin-1.6.2.jar
axis2-clustering-1.6.2.jar
```

and I want to find their location and delete them
I try to use the following script

```
#!/bin/ksh
file="/path/to/file/jars.txt"

while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
    for i in $(find  $BASE_DIR/root/ -name "$line"); do
        echo "delete $i"
        rm "$i"
    done
done <"$file"
```

the row `echo "$line"` print the file name correct as it should but in the for loop, the result comes empty

if I use `find  $BASE_DIR/root/ -name "axiom-api-1.2.13.jar"` it's work and finds all the files

so what am I missing here?
why the for loop not working with the $line as a param?

Comment: Does your file of filenames perhaps have extra  spaces at the end of lines?

Comment: @Shawn I thought about it, and there is none

Comment: Sure about that? Because there are in the sample one in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file jars.txt created on windows and when I use it on Linux it has format errors
the solution is to create a new file in Linux and copy the data

Comment: by `*format errors*` I'm assuming the file (created on windows) contains windows EOL characters (`\r`); if this is the case, consider running `dos2unix <filename>` (on linux) to strip out the windows EOL character (`\r`)

Comment: You can accept your own answer (or delete the question) so people stop opening your question in an attempt to answer it.